# No subscribers under Subscriber Organizations tab in license management app (LMA)

Tags: managed-package, licenses, isv, partner, lma

We have installed License Management App (LMA) into our business organization for one of our packages. Now we want to use the LMA to login to our customer orgs that have installed other packages. I can see the package record and package version records in the app but when I click on subscriber organizations tab, I don't see any subscribers. I recently created licenses for one of the customers manually but still don't see the subscribers. The customers have installed the packages (released) months ago so it must be a configuration issue.

On the same note, our customers do not see us in the list of entities they can grant login access to.

Comment: I think the managed package gets associated with the LMA org when it gets created. Try creating a new managed package and then installing that in the subscriber orgs. I only have subscribers show up when they install a version of the managed package that was created after the LMA was setup. Same with granting login access. Only those on package versions created after LMA setup can grant login access.

Comment: I'm still struggling to make this work. Our package is not on AppExchange. It has only passed security review and we have not listed it. Do I have to create the versions manually? Does the version need to match exactly what has been installed into customer orgs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to the Package in the LMA there is a "Refresh Licenses" button. Press that and then wait 24 hours for all the Subscriber information to be refreshed.

Otherwise you need to wait for the subscribers to install newer versions of the managed package that was created after the LMA app was setup.

Comment: I clicked on "Refresh Licences" and it's been more than 24 hours. I still see no licences and no subscribers.

Comment: @DavidJ I suspect the only other option is to wait until the subscribers update to a managed package version that was created after the LMA app was installed. Each time you create a new managed package it registers itself with the LMA app.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I see the managed package was created in LMA when we created it. However, the latestVersion field is not updated properly. I want to make sure that we have this working after this upload. Otherwise, we will have another quarter of not having access to subscriber orgs.